# Event listener doesn't work. it says event is not defined in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a novice to jquery/ javascript

I tried to use the event listener in html

Here is the demo:
http://jsbin.com/ximezaqe/1/edit

Clicking on the link should trigger a alert. but it doesn't.
I checked the console and it says:

menu is not defined . (menu being the event in the event listener)

I think I am missing something. I copied the code from elsewhere but it doesn't appear to work.

HTML

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:menu()" >
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag has-icon"></i> a link
  </a>
</li>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function trigger() {
   window.alert('Hello!');   
  }

  function menu() {
   setTimeout('trigger()', 2000);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Your functions are local to your `ready` handler's scope. So-called-obtrusive event handlers require all names to be accessible from the global scope.

Comment: Every function creates a new scope, so the functions inside the ready function is out of the global scope and not accessible from the inline event handler in the global scope. You should be using proper event handlers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a class="clickable" href="#" >
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag has-icon"></i> a link
    </a>
</li>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function menu() {
        setTimeout(trigger, 2000);
    }
    function trigger() {
       window.alert('Hello!');   
    }

    $('.clickable').on('click',function(){
        menu();     
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Great, if you have any further questions, just ask

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<li><a href="javascript:;" onlick="javascript:menu();" >
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag has-icon"></i> a link
                      </a>
                </li>
```

and your menu function must fall outside the

```
$(document).ready({});
```

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//
});
function menu(){
//Do your stuff
}
```